# How to impove pinecone/openAI/langchain/python setup

Tags: python, flask, openai-api, pinecone

I’m having an issue training a Pinecone/langchain/model.

For some reason, when I feed the data into Pinecone and I query a question I don’t get get correct answers even for simple stuff like asking “what’s is the title of the document”

I was able to get the correct answer by only feeding the first 500 characters… which is kinda weird

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
# process_message.py
from flask import request
import pinecone
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores import Pinecone
from langchain.chains.question_answering import load_qa_chain
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
import json
import os
import configparser
from middleware.auth import check_authorization
from services.api.firebase.files import FileFireStorage
from langchain.document_loaders import UnstructuredPDFLoader, OnlinePDFLoader, PyPDFLoader
from services.util.file import TextUtils
from llama_index import SimpleDirectoryReader
from llama_index import GPTVectorStoreIndex
from tqdm import tqdm
import time
import docx
from io import BytesIO
from openai.embeddings_utils import get_embedding
import openai
import time



def construct_prompt(query,index):
  matches = search_docs(query,index)


  chosen_text = []
  for match in matches:
    chosen_text.append(match['metadata']['text'])
  mod_text = "\n".join([text[0] for text in chosen_text])
  

  prompt = """Answer the question as truthfully as possible using the context below, and if the answer is no within the context, say 'I don't know.'"""
  prompt += "\n\n"
  prompt += "Context: " + mod_text

  prompt += "\n\n"
  prompt += "Question: " + query
  prompt += "\n"
  prompt += "Answer: "



  return prompt

def search_docs(query,index):
  xq = openai.Embedding.create(input=query, engine="text-embedding-ada-002")['data'][0]['embedding']
  res = index.query([xq], top_k=5, include_metadata=True)
  chosen_text = []
  for match in res['matches']:
    chosen_text = match['metadata']
  return res['matches']

def answer_question(query,index):
  prompt = construct_prompt(query,index)
 

  res = openai.Completion.create(
      prompt=prompt,
      model="text-davinci-003",
      max_tokens=1000,
      temperature=0.0,
  )
  
  return res.choices[0]["text"]

def create_index_if_needed(index_name):
    if index_name not in pinecone.list_indexes():
        # Create the index
        pinecone.create_index(index_name, dimension=1536)
        
        # Wait until the index is ready
        while True:
            index_info = pinecone.get_index_info(index_name)
            status = index_info['status']
            
            if status == 'created':
                break  # Index is ready
            elif status == 'failed':
                raise Exception('Index creation failed')
            
            time.sleep(1)  # Wait for 1 second before checking again
    
    return pinecone.Index(index_name)

def update_data(index,chunks_with_embeddigns):
  batch_size = 64  # process everything in batches of 64
  for i in tqdm(range(0, len(chunks_with_embeddigns), batch_size)):
    data_batch = chunks_with_embeddigns[i: i+batch_size]

    # set end position of batch
    i_end = min(i+batch_size, len(chunks_with_embeddigns))
    # get batch meta
    text_batch = [item['text'] for item in data_batch]
    # get ids
    ids_batch = [str(n) for n in range(i, i_end)]
    # get embeddings
    embeds = [item['embedding'] for item in data_batch]
    # prep metadata and upsert batch
    meta = [{'text': text_batch} for text_batch in zip(text_batch)] # you can add more fields here

    to_upsert = zip(ids_batch, embeds, meta)
    # upsert to Pinecone
    index.upsert(vectors=list(to_upsert))
  
def chunk_text(chunk_size,data):
  # Split the large string into chunks
  text_chunks = [data[i:i+chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(data), chunk_size)]
  # return [data[i:i+chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(data), chunk_size)]
    # remove all chunks shorter than 10 words and strip the rest
  return [string.strip().strip('\n') for string in text_chunks if len(string.split()) >= 10]
    
def create_chunks_with_embeddigns(text_chunks):
  chunks_with_embeddigns = []
  for chunk in tqdm(text_chunks):
      embedding = get_embedding(chunk, engine='text-embedding-ada-002')
      chunks_with_embeddigns.append({"text": chunk, "embedding": embedding})
  return chunks_with_embeddigns  
  

def upload_data():
    print('upload_data()')
    
    body = request.get_json()
    data = json.dumps(body['data'])
    # company id is the index
    companyId = json.dumps(body['companyId']).replace('"', '').lower()
    # data = data[:500]
    
    
  
    # Create a ConfigParser object and read the config.ini file
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('config.ini')
    openai_key = config.get('openai', 'OPENAI_API_KEY')
    pinecone_env_key = config.get('pinecone', 'PINECONE_ENVIRONMENT')
    pinecone_api_key = config.get('pinecone', 'PINECONE_API_KEY')

    openai.api_key = openai_key
    pinecone.init(api_key=pinecone_api_key, environment=pinecone_env_key)
    index = create_index_if_needed(index_name=companyId)


    # THESE THREE LINES FEED DATA INTO THE SYSTEM FOR THE FIRST TIME RUNNING THE CODE
    # text_chunks = chunk_text(chunk_size=1000,data=data)
    # chunks_with_embeddigns = create_chunks_with_embeddigns(text_chunks=text_chunks)
    # update_data(index=index,chunks_with_embeddigns=chunks_with_embeddigns)

    try:
      print( answer_question( 'what is the title/name of the document?',index))
        # print(answer_question("what documents are being refered to for more information?", index))
       
    except Exception as e:
        # Code to handle the exception and print the error
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

    return 'hi'
```

Comment: i think you should manage some of these data in the metadata while loading?
I'm curious to know what you have done